Why the ideal $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal with respect to any norm
As you can see in the link, book shows that the ideal $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal in  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$. I believe that I completely understand the proof however the last sentence makes me confused. "$I$ is not principal so $R$ is not ED (with respect to any norm)." They refer norm to be $N:\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb Z^{+}\cup\{0\}$ defined by $a+b\sqrt{-5}\mapsto a^2+5b^2$.
First of all, of course I know that if $R$ is ED then its ideal must be principal. So, basically, they find the ideal $I$ which is not principal wrt usual norm. Hence, $R$ is not $ED$. However, my question is how can they be so sure that there is no another norm on $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ which $I$ is principal?
On the other hand, is it enough to say that a ring $R$ is not ED if one finds an ideal which is not principal wrt some norm?

The fact that an ideal is principal or not is an algebraic condition that has nothing to do with norms.

In fact, being a Euclidean domain implies being a PID, so if $R$ admits a non-principal ideal, it is not a PID hence cannot have any proper Euclidean function. Back to the case of $I$, the usual norm assures that there is no proper element whose norm divides the ones of $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$, hence $I$ cannot be principal, as we know that for the usual norm, $a|b \implies a | Nr(b)$

@RHspqr How do we know there is another norm different than the usual doesn't assure that there is no element whose norm divides $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$?

Principal ideals have nothing t9 d9 with norms. They are either principal or not.

The standard norm can be used to prove an ideal is not principal. But another norm will not then make it principal.

It is just a matter of logic: the contrapositive of "there is some Euclidean function for $R \Rightarrow R$ is a PID" is "$R$ is not a PID $\Rightarrow$ there is no Euclidean function for $R$" $\ \ $

Thank you so much for your comments. Now, I'm satisfied.
